# PHP Do something when session destroyed

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, sessionid

I was wondering if I could determine if someone's session has been ended and if I could do something if it has.

So for example, if session has ended set player status to offline.

Comment: Do you mean, if you destroyed the session?  Or if the user stops visiting your site?

Comment: Are you using an application framework (e.g., Symfony, CodeIgniter, Cake, etc.)?

Comment: Well stops visiting my site I guess. So if they close the browser ect

Comment: You need to have a reference to a user's session ID to do it the way you're describing. Store their PHP session ID in the database then make a script that checks if those sessions are still active. Then I assume online/offline is also stored in the database, so update that accordingly. Do you need more specifics?

Comment: The Session is not automatically destroyed when the user closes the browser. The session cookie might be deleted, but the session still lives on the server until it is deleted after a certain time (that can be set using php.ini)

Answer (score 1):

If a user does not make a request to the server you cannot reliably know when their session has ended unless you use a database system. For example, you have a sessions table:

```
session_id | user_id | session_start_time
```

Whenever you load a page you look if a session_start_time is old enough to be deleted. For example:

```
if (($data['session_start_time'] + USER_SESSION_TTL) < time()) {
    // delete row
}
```

`USER_SESSION_TTL` is the time that the user's session stays alive if he is inactive.

Now if the user does not have a session associated with him, you can safely assume he is offline. I generalized a bit, but it can be applied to many systems.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but what does this part mean. USER_SESSION_TTL

Comment: I added clarification for that part. Its basically the time (in seconds) a users session stays alive if he doesn't visit your site (is not active).

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in mechanism for this, though, if you implement your own session handler, you can probably do something about it.

See http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php for some ideas.